# Request parameters not recognizing &amp; as separator

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, xhtml

I have an HttpHandler that reads the parameters from the request URL by simply using context.Request["param1"]. The thing is that my website is xHTML compliant so all links are encoded. So I have a link in the format of: http://mydomain.com/?param1=a&param2=b.

The problem is that Request["param2"] is not recognized. Instead it thinks the second parameter is "amp;param2". It does not realize that the & is representing & in the URL. How would I tell "Request" that the links are expected to be xHTML compliant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to [UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w.aspx) your links, not [HTMLEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3te6wfz.aspx).

The first one gives `& = %26` while the latter (the one you're using) gives `& = &amp;` and the handler is breaking the parameters by the first & in `&amp;`

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `Request.QueryString`, not Request.

For example:

```
context.Request.QueryString["param1"]
context.Request.QueryString["param2"]
```

Comment: hmmm this has not changed the behavior

Comment: Request will access querystring. It also accesses several other collections. Go here for details: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETParamsCollectionVsQueryStringFormsVsRequestindexAndDoubleDecoding.aspx

Comment: true, but irrelevant to the question.

Comment: I just noticed that you only have a `?` in the URL (and not a page name), which could be throwing the query string parsing off. Do you have control over how the URL is generated?

Comment: @JohnGibb To elaborate, Request.QueryString vs Request has no bearing on the problem at hand. This answer is incorrect.

Comment: @jm2: I am sorry, but you are incorrect. Request.Item, which is the default property for Request, will return QueryString OR Form OR Cookies OR ServerVariables with the specified key. Attempting to extract QueryString properties with the default property is NOT guaranteed to return a QueryString value.

Comment: @competent_tech That is correct, just as I had pointed out in the link I posted which elaborates on the topic. I never claimed otherwise. My point is that your answer to the question at hand is wrong even if your advice in general is subjectively correct. Using Request.QueryString vs Request, while generally advisable, will not solve the OP's issue.

Answer (score 0):

The ampersand in your url that separates your GET (ie querystring/request) parameters still needs to be an '&'. If you're displaying an ampersand in actual XHTML, that's when you will use the XHTML encoding. XHTML encoding an ampersand for use as a parameter separator in a URL will not be recognized as such.